# Creating objects in Java

Tags: java

This is the code

```
public class CreateObjectDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Point    originOne     = new Point(23,94)

        rectTwo.origin = originOne;

        System.out.println("X postion of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.x);
        System.out.println("Y Position of rectTwo: " + rectTwo.origin.y);

        rectTwo.move(40, 72);
        System.out.println("X position of rectTwo : " + rectTwo.origin.x);
        System.out.println("Y position of rectTwo : " + rectTwo.origin.y);
    }
}`
```

I have this code from Java tutorial, but I have trouble running it, it shows error of "Point" and "Rectangle" , error said "Point" & "Rectangle" can nont resolve into a type. What am I missing here ? 
I am beginner in Java, so I am very silly .

Comment: Inorder to use those classes, you have to implement them.

Comment: Add `import java.awt.Point;` and `import java.awt.Rectangle` to above your `class` decleration

Comment: Also, I think you need to use dimension with point, not two integers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle(java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tutorial you are using is from the following link:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Class/CreateObjectDemo.htm

The code in the tutorial works. It seems you didn't copy the "Point" and "Rectangle" classes into your file. This is what you need to do:

1. Copy the entire tutorial code into a file named "CreateObjectDemo.java"
2. run "javac CreateObjectDemo.java" on the command line
3. run "java CreateObjectDemo" on the command line

> ```
> Width of rect_one: 100
> Height of rect_one: 200
> Area of rect_one: 20000
> X Position of rect_two: 23
> Y Position of rect_two: 94
> X Position of rect_two: 40
> Y Position of rect_two: 72
> ```

Answer (score 1):

add import statements

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```